# case statement picking duplicate values in databricks using sparksql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a scenario like populate a column with 1 or 0 based on the given condition-

`select * from table where dno not in (43, 44)`
--if we get a record then 1 else 0

so after putting simple case statement like

`select distinct id , dno, case when dno not in (43, 44) then 1 else 0 end as output from table`

I am getting an output like below-

| id | dno | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 43 | 1 |
| a | 41 | 0 |
| b | 41 | 0 |
| d | 44 | 1 |

I am getting duplicate records here but I just want the first record which is having 1.

**Can anyone help me to write an optimized query for this as I am already joining many tables using sparksql.**

Comment: Hi @tyro_incode, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want the first record which is having 1

To get the first record, we must use **`Limit`** clause along with the query. It will return the records by applying limit provided by you.

***Query***

```sql
select distinct Id , Dno, case when Dno in (43,44) then 1 else 0 end as output from Table where Dno in (43, 44) limit 1
```

***Output***

[image: Query output]